# Effects on rectangles

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

I want to make my diagram’s rectangles look like these, the arrows and rectangles are in bold plus they have a shadow effect:

[image]

Right now they look like this:

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
forked edges,
for tree={draw,align=center,edge={-latex}}
[Recommendation\\ Systems
 [1.1]
 [1.2
  [1.2.1
   [1.2.1.1]
   [1.2.1.2]
  ]
  [1.2.2
   [1.2.2.1]
   [1.2.2.2]
   [1.2.2.3]
  ]
 ]
 [1.3]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta,bending,shadows.blur,shapes.multipart,
shapes.geometric,calc}
\tikzset{database/.style={cylinder,aspect=0.3,draw,shape border rotate=90,path picture={
\draw let \p1=($(path picture bounding box.east)-(path picture bounding
box.west)$) in 
foreach \XX in {1,2,3}  {([yshift=-0.15*\x1-\XX*1ex]path picture bounding box.north west) 
arc(180:360:\x1/2 and 0.3*\x1/2)};
}}}
\newsavebox\LoopArrow
\sbox\LoopArrow{\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[thick,-{Latex[bend]}] (90:2em) arc(90:455:2em);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,
grimsel/.style={rectangle split,rectangle split parts=2,draw,thick,
    fill=white,blur shadow,rounded corners,text width=10em,align=center}]
 \node[grimsel] (datap)  {Data preprocessing\nodepart[align=left]{two}
    \textit{blablabla.py}\\
    xyz\\ 
    abc};
 \node[grimsel,below=3em of datap] (fine)  {Finetuning\nodepart[align=left]{two}
  \textit{blablabla.py}\\
  \makebox[10em][c]{\usebox\LoopArrow}};   
 \node[grimsel,above right=2em and 4em of fine.east] (algo) {Algorithms\nodepart[align=left]{two}
    \textit{blablabla.py}\\
    xyz\\ 
    abc};
 \node[grimsel,below right=2em and 4em of fine.east] (utils) {Utils\nodepart[align=left]{two}
    Evaluation\\ 
    abc\\
    xyz\\ 
    abc};
 \node[left=3em of datap,thick,fill=white,blur shadow,database,shape aspect=0.3,minimum height=8em] (SQL)  {PostGreSQL}; 
 \begin{scope}[very thick,-Latex]
  \draw (SQL) -- (datap);
  \draw (datap) -- (fine);
  \draw (algo.west) -- ++ (-2em,0) |- (fine);
  \draw (utils.west) -- ++ (-2em,0) |- (fine);
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or a forest version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur,shapes.multipart}
\tikzset{grimsel/.style={rectangle split,rectangle split parts=2,draw,
    fill=white,blur shadow,rounded corners,align=center}}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\NodeTitle}[2][]{#2\nodepart[align=left,text width={width("#2")}]{two}}
\begin{forest}
forked edges,
for tree={grimsel,edge={-latex}}
[{\NodeTitle{Recommendation Systems} bla bla}
 [{\NodeTitle{1.1} bla}]
 [{\NodeTitle{1.2} bla}
  [{\NodeTitle{1.2.1} bla}
   [{\NodeTitle{1.2.1.1} bla}]
   [{\NodeTitle{1.2.1.2} bla}]
  ]
  [{\NodeTitle{1.2.2} bla}
   [{\NodeTitle{1.2.2.1} bla}]
   [{\NodeTitle{1.2.2.2} bla}]
   [{\NodeTitle{1.2.2.3} bla}]
  ]
 ]
 [{1.3\nodepart[align=left]{two} bla}]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can I make the border of the rectangles look bold? Almost like the arrows but not that much. Thank you!

Comment: @naveganTeX Just add `thick` (or `line width=...pt`) to the definition of `grimsel`, I added this to the upper code.

Comment: I just saw it!!! Bla bla bla... chapeau!